# How to count files in the FileSystem

Tags: f#

```
FileSystem = [Dir ("Dir3",[]); Dir ("Dir1",[Dir ("Dir2",[])])]
```

Let's suppose that this is my FileSystem. I want to count the number of files in that FileSystem recursively. Can someone guide me through this? I could not find related documentation and don't know where to look.

```
 type FileSystem = Element list and Element = | File of string | Dir of string * FileSystem
```

My FileSystem structure is like above.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `Dir` and your representation of a File?

Comment: I edited my question according to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of recursive query usually relies on a fold function to traverse the hierarchy.

A fold function takes a function that can be used to aggregate the results. In the below example, the inner `counter` function takes the accumulated count so far, and the next element in the list. We then check the element, and if it's a file we add 1 to our count, otherwise we add the count of files in child subdirectories.

```
let rec countFiles =
             let counter i el =
                 i + match el with
                     | File _ -> 1
                     | Dir (_, children) -> countFiles children
             List.fold counter 0
```

Running the following:

```
printfn "%A" <| countFiles
    [ File "a"
      Dir ("d1", [
                  File "b"
                  File "c"
                  ])
      ]

// yields 3
```